# The relationship between VertexLabels and VertexList

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have constructed a graph. For the sake of brevity, I changed the labels of vertices of the graph. But I found it no more convenient to manipulate it further.

```
S = {{{2, 3}, {2, 7}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{2, 4}, {2, 5}}, {{2, 
     6}, {1, 2}}};
G = RelationGraph[DisjointQ[#1, #2] &, List @@ S, 
  VertexLabels -> Table[S[[i]] -> Subscript["S", i], {i, 4}]]
```

[image]

```
VertexDegree[G, Subscript["S", 1]](*Output as is.*)
```

I found out through the  function `VertexList` that the labels of the vertices are still not modified.

```
VertexList[G]
(*output  {{{2, 3}, {2, 7}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{2, 4}, {2, 5}}, {{2, 6}, {1, 2}}}*)
```

Why not $\{S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4\}$?

---

The effect of maple's `RelabelVertices` function seems to be what I want.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VertexLabels` set only *visual* labels. They have no bearing on how one manipulates the graph.

You may be looking for [`VertexReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexReplace.html) which allows for changing the vertex names.

*Names* are what you use to refer to vertices when programming.

*Labels* are merely a piece of text displayed next to each vertex when visualizing graph.